# Java AES encryption example

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes

when I tried to implement this code which is (AES algorithm written in Java), I found an error in these lines:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

            setEncryptedString(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

            setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));
```

The main code is :

```
package trytry;


import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.print.DocFlavor.STRING;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;



public class AES
{

    
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey ;
    private static byte[] key ;
    
    private static String decryptedString;
    private static String encryptedString;
 
    
    public static void setKey(String myKey){
        
   
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(key.length);
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
            System.out.println(key.length);
            System.out.println(new String(key,"UTF-8"));
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            
            
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
              
    

    }
    
    public static String getDecryptedString() {
        return decryptedString;
    }

    public static void setDecryptedString(String decryptedString) {
        AES.decryptedString = decryptedString;
    }

    public static String getEncryptedString() {
        return encryptedString;
    }

    public static void setEncryptedString(String encryptedString) {
        AES.encryptedString = encryptedString;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        
         
            setEncryptedString(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: "+e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
           
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: "+e.toString());

        }
        return null;
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
 
                final String strToEncrypt = "My text to encrypt";
                final String strPssword = "encryptor key";
                AES.setKey(strPssword);
               
                AES.encrypt(strToEncrypt.trim());
                
                System.out.println("String to Encrypt: " + strToEncrypt); 
                System.out.println("Encrypted: " + AES.getEncryptedString());
           
                final String strToDecrypt =  AES.getEncryptedString();
                AES.decrypt(strToDecrypt.trim());
               
                System.out.println("String To Decrypt : " + strToDecrypt);
                System.out.println("Decrypted : " + AES.getDecryptedString());
        
    }
     
}
```

just to know I tried to add: JRE System Library but does not work.

Comment: You need to add Apache-Commons library first. Also, show the stack trace related to the error/exception.

Comment: download commons library and add to your project lib. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/org-apache/org-apache-commons-codec.jar.zip) is link to download jar.

Comment: Thanks for your help I did add the  Apache-Commons  from the link that you put here, the error on :
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
 is gone but I still have errors on the rest 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));
```

should be

```
setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt)),
    Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

I doubt it will make a difference, but if you're explicit in encryption (and you should be), then you should be explicit with the decryption.

In any case, something more descriptive than "I found an error" or "I have errors" would be very helpful. (Exceptions and stacktraces or the Eclipse and/or compiler error messages.)